# How to integrate Invisible reCaptcha to a website, without a form

Tags: recaptcha

My current task: restrict bot activity on a website.
Solution: integrate invisible reCaptcha and fire it on page load. If a user passes the humanity test, website continuous loading, if not user will be challenged.

Can someone help we with advice how to integrate it that way?

Comment: This sounds like bad User Experience to me, what is the actual scenario of this?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I appreciate the concern and I am aware of the consequences. If googles algorithms will work as expected there will be no bad UE. For the more, if I succeed in the integration, the result will be used in a/b test on a limited amount of traffic, so no harm to majority.

Comment: Okay, so the docs allow you to invoke this programatically with JS. I would imagine you can bind a success callback/hook on that to trigger a redirect or similar - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute

Comment: @AndyHolmes As the documentation is a bit complicated. Is there a need for any back-end verification is my case? For example, should I configure the recaptchalib.php file or it's value is outdated?

Comment: Complicated in which way? That link I added should be a start in what you need I think

Comment: I suspect if you try to trigger the recaptcha programmatically on page load, there will not have been sufficient user interaction for recaptcha to decide you are not a bot. So it should be tied to a button-clicking activity, such as "Welcome! Click OK to continue". Yes, you always need to do server-side verification. That step can be integrated with setting a cookie so that the site functions without further recaptcha involvement.

Answer (score 2):

I recently posted an answer detailing how to programmatically render and trigger invisible recaptcha for ajax forms. You can read the [full answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42892255/5249729). But in short, use api method:

- `grecaptcha.render()` api to render the invisible recaptcha by passing `size="invisible"`
- `grecaptcha.getResponse()` to check if user has passed the test. It returns a token. If token is empty string, it means user is not verified human yet.
- `grecaptcha.execute()` to programmatically show a challenge to user. You can pass a `callback` function in options to `render()` api method which gets called back when user has passed the test.